# apache tiles not rendering correctly (shows plain text) in struts2

Tags: html, struts2, tiles

i am working on a struts2 web app where i am using Apache tiles2 framework.
            The Code is Working Fine on localhost but when i up the code on server  it renders the tiled pages as plain text. can anyone please tell me where is the problem.
i mean to say that the page is displayed as plaintext on browser-side.

this is how it is rendered in browser.. Screenshot - http://i42.tinypic.com/2vnj686.jpg

kindly help me if anyone have a solution....

here is my tiles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
           "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
           "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd"  >
    <!--        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd" -->
    <tiles-definitions>

        <definition name="BaseDef" template="/adminpanel/template/BaseLayout.jsp">

            <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />
            <put-attribute name="css" value="/adminpanel/template/extracss.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="js" value="/adminpanel/template/js.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="header" value="/adminpanel/template/header.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/adminpanel/template/body.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="footer" value="/adminpanel/template/footer.jsp" />

    </definition>

        <definition name="LatestMaterial" extends="BaseDef">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Latest Exam Material " />
            <put-attribute name="css" value="/adminpanel/template/newtablecss2.jsp" />              
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/adminpanel/Pages/latestexammaterial.jsp" />
            </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

here is my BaseLayout.jsp

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="css"/>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="js"/>
         <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="main">
                        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
                                        <div id="body">
                                                 <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
                                        </div></div>
                        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>

        </body>
        </html>
```

this is how i used it in struts.xml

```
   <package name="wz.admin"  extends="struts-default,json-default,tiles-default">
      <action name="LatestMaterial" class="org.wz.admin.LatestMaterialAction">
        <result type="tiles">LatestMaterial</result>
    </action>
    </package>
```

Comment: Is your CSS imported correctly? Have you checked if the HTML rendered part of the `/adminpanel/template/extracss.jsp` page points correctly to your CSS?

Comment: yes i cross checked it..it is imported correctly.. and even if it isn't It should atleast show some weird html page with no css instead of just plain text..  isn't it ?

Comment: Any exceptions in console?

Comment: no exception...everything is fine according to tomcat..

Comment: Give a look at this [Example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html). Have you correctly configured the deployment descriptor and the tiles listener in the `web.xml`?

Comment: yes @araknoid i have configured it correctly.. it works perfectly on localhost so i dont think its a configuration error.. is it ?

Comment: @user2273752 Since on localhost it's working perfectly, seems a problem related to the deploy. Have you checked if there are any differences between what you have deployed on your localhost and on the server?

Comment: @araknoid what kind of differences?  Actually it collects all the required tiles but the complete code than is shown as plain text.. thats only the problem...

Comment: @user2273752 Check if all the libraries (mainly the tiles ones) and config files are all deployed on server.

Comment: @araknoid i checked the libraries , they are right there where they should be...

Comment: @user2273752 Can you add to your question what you are getting displayed in the browser?

Comment: @araknoid here is how it is displayed in browser...see the screenshot http://i42.tinypic.com/2vnj686.jpg

Comment: @user2273752 There are strange HTML comments in the code you display in the web `<!--` and `-->` that are like commenting the major part of your code.

Comment: @araknoid actually i commented tat code myself to check if the page works if i exclude some part...  that didnt... so thats not a problem ..if i remove the comments the problem remains the same

Comment: Today i tried modifying BaseLayout.jsp as a simple jsp.. means i didnt used any tiles definitions in it... a simple jsp with no tiles inserted just coming from tiles... but it still didnt work whereas other jsp's on websites are working quite well... whats wrong with tiles ?? is this can be any versioning issue.

Comment: Anyone help please...  This issue is making me mad

Answer (score 0):

I checked with a fresh mind your code and I think the problem is your `struts.xml` since everything seems fine. I'm not sure at 100% but try to change your `struts.xml` into this:

```
    <package name="wz.admin" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="LatestMaterial" class="org.wz.admin.LatestMaterialAction">
            <result type="tiles">LatestMaterial</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Also, even if the `success` result is the default one, you should name your results in order to avoid misurdenstand when managing multiple results:

```
    <result name="success" type="tiles">LatestMaterial</result>
```

This was just a suggestion that my architect gave me when i was working with struts. In the end I found it really usefull.

Comment: The `success` result is default.

Comment: @AleksandrM I know that `success` is the default result but was just a suggestion that my architect at the time gave me and i found it usefull when i worked hard with struts.

Comment: You could include that into your answer.

Comment: thanks @araknoid for your support..  yesterday i found a fix for that... i was using struts 2.3.8 with tiles version 2.0.6 ..actually i want to say that i was using the same files that were shipped with struts 2.3.8 package ..but yesterday i downloaded a new plugin of struts tiles i.e. 2.3.16 and used that with tiles 2.0.6 and that worked like a charm....i dont know why i faced the problem because if it is shipped with package it should work fine...thanks araknoid for your efforts and thanks others for trying...